# "New setup resulted in a(?) much better performance." - is it correct?

Tags: articles

Is it correct to put the article "a" after "resulted in"? example:

> The new setup resulted **in a much** better performance.
>
> The new setup resulted **in much** better performance.

is it correct?

Comment: You probably want to add an article before "new"... "The new setup..."

Comment: corrected       ..........

Answer (score 3):

As far as I'm concerned, they're both fine... but some context here is helpful.  Note that "performance" has two relevant definitions, use which you're referring to determine whether the article is appropriate or not.

The version with the article makes more sense for a one-time or short term performance, say

> The new setup for the orchestra resulted in a much better performance.

In this case, the "performance" is a show or exhibition.

Whereas the version without the article makes more sense for regular or continuous performance, as of a car or computer:

> The new setup for my computer resulted in much better performance.

So, in this case "performance" means "ability to do work".

Comment: the increased performance remained stable so the latter meaning is that what I need

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a ton of difference between the two and you could use either.

However, "a much better performance" could be taken to mean that you only ran it once. Like it was set up one way, you changed it, ran the program, and it was better.

In contrast, just "much better performance" seems to imply you have used the program many times after changing the set up and it is consistently better.

Comment: the increased performance remained stable so the latter meaning is that what I need

Answer (score 1):

"A performance" generally implies a human act of some theatrical nature, e.g. standing up and telling jokes, or a theatre group putting on a play.

"performance" (without the article, 'a') is used when discussing whether a machine ran code fast or slowly.